# Adding price to total when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to add a $5.00 charge whenever the txtBwayEDUGift checkbox is selected. The javascript code I currently have is reducing the amount when checkbox is unchecked, but not applying the charge when selected. I can provide additonal code if needed.

Here is my input type from my aspx page:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txtBwayEDUGift" id="txtBwayEDUGift" onchange="checkboxAdd(this);" checked="checked" />
```

Here is my javascript:

```
{
    var divPrevAmt;
    if (type == 0)
    {
        divPrevAmt = document.getElementById("divBwayGiftPrevAmt");
    }
    else if (type == 1)
    {
        divPrevAmt = document.getElementById("divBwayEDUGiftPrevPmt");
    }
    var txtAmt = document.getElementById(obj);
    var amt = txtAmt.value;
    amt = amt.toString().replace("$","");
    amt = amt.replace(",","");
    var prevAmt = divPrevAmt.innerHTML;
    try
    {
        amt = amt * 1;
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        txtAmt.value = "";
        return;
    }
    if (amt >= 0) //get the previous amount if any
    {
        if (type == 0)
        {
           if (prevAmt.toString().length > 0)
           {
                prevAmt = prevAmt * 1;
           }
           else
           {
                prevAmt = 0;
           }
        }
        else if (type == 1)
        {
           if (prevAmt.toString().length > 0)
           {
                prevAmt = prevAmt * 1;
           }
           else
           {
                prevAmt = 0;
           }
        }
    //now update the master total
    var total = document.getElementById("txtTotal");
    var dTotal = total.value.toString().replace("$","");
    dTotal = dTotal.replace(",","");
    dTotal = dTotal * 1;
    var newTotal = dTotal - prevAmt;
    newTotal = newTotal + amt;
    divPrevAmt.innerHTML = amt.toString();
    newTotal = addCommas(newTotal);
    amt = addCommas(amt);
    txtAmt.value = "$" + amt;
    total.value = "$" + newTotal;
   }
   else
   {
        txtAmt.value = "";
        return;
   }
}
function disable()
{
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById("txtTotal");
    var txt = txtTotal.value;
    txtTotal.value = txt;
    var BwayGift = document.getElementById("txtBwayGift");
    BwayGift.focus();
}
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    var newTotal = x1 + x2;
    if (newTotal.toString().indexOf(".") != -1)
    {
        newTotal = newTotal.substring(0,newTotal.indexOf(".") + 3);
    }
    return newTotal;
}
function checkChanged()
{
    var cb = document.getElementById("cbOperaGala");
    if (cb.checked == true)
    {
        var tableRow = document.getElementById("trCheckbox");
        tableRow.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/otTableRowSelect.jpg')";
    }
    else if (cb.checked == false)
    {
        var tableRow = document.getElementById("trCheckbox");
        tableRow.style.backgroundImage = "";
    }
}
function alertIf()
{
    var i = 0;
    for (i=5;i<=10;i++)
    {
        try{
        var subtotal2 = document.getElementById("txtSubTotal" + i);
        var dSubtotal2 = subtotal2.value;
        dSubtotal2 = dSubtotal2.replace("$","");
        dSubtotal2 = dSubtotal2 * 1;}
        catch (Error){dSubtotal2 = 0}
        if (dSubtotal2 > 0)
        {
            alert("You have selected the I want it all package, \n however you have also selected individual tickets to the same events. \n If you meant to do this, please disregard this message.");
            break;
        }
    }
}

function disableEnterKey(e)
{
 var key;      
 if(window.event)
      key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
 else
      key = e.which; //firefox      

return (key != 13);
}

    //Add $5.00 donation to cart

    function checkboxAdd(ctl) {
    if (ctl.checked == true) {
    //            alert("adding $5");
        calculateTotal(5, "A");
    } else {
    //            alert("deducting $5");
        calculateTotal( 5, "S");
    }
} 

</script>
```

Comment: java is not equal to javascript and neither is not equal to c# or asp.net

Comment: Does your `alert` fire when checking the box? What does `calculateTotal` look like?

Comment: jQuery will solve this problem in only 10 lines!

Comment: Keep in mind that users can manually edit javascript, which could end up with people submitting negative charges to your servers if not properly validated.

Comment: Yeah If he is going to make economic website then it is harmful!

Comment: The alert does fire when checking the box. But i'm concerned as to why the amount is not changing. I'm open for any suggestions. Please share your magical 10 lines of jquery if you can :)

Comment: Good advice @jbabey! I am going to look further into the validation once I can get the functionality to work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the context of the scenario.  When a user clicks the checkbox are you making an HTTP request to the server?  Or is this a simple form POST page?  What is `calculateTotal()` doing?

Comment: @hiyopp Yes, making a request to the server. Sorry, I left that part out.

Comment: calculateTotal() is part of the javascript that calculates the shopping cart total (I just added the code for you to see. I included calculateTotal() in the function checkboxAdd(txtBwayEDUGift) because my goal is to to add $5.00 to the cart total. I apologize in advance, I am working with code from a previous developer...

Comment: @Yaknowss So to confirm, the `txtBwayEDUGift` checkbox sends an HTTP request to the server (when clicked), to either add or subtract $5 from the **total**, right?  Where in your JavaScript are you making the server call?  It appears that you are actually updating the total via JavaScript (no HTTP request).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. So the functionality I had in place was fine.

```
//Add $5.00 donation to cart
function checkboxAdd(txtBwayEDUGift) {
    if (txtBwayEDUGift.checked == true) {
//            alert("adding $5");
        calculateTotal(5, "A");
    } else {
//            alert("deducting $5");
        calculateTotal(5, "S");
    }
}
```

But I needed to add a load function:

```
function load() {
    calculateTotal(5, "A");
}

<body onload="load()">
```

Along with adding a reference to my c# page:

```
if (txtBwayEDUGift.Checked)
        {
            addDonations(5.00, 93);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery :)

```
$(txtBwayEDUGift).change(calculateTotal(5, "S"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out. Just bare with me because I rarely use jquery. Is this one line of code going to replace my entire javascript function?

Comment: I think i have anwsered a wrong question, the code has changed rapidly since i commented on it?